# canOpenUrl and International Phone Formats

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

For the iPhone (not the simulator),

I'm wondering if canOpenUrl for dialing phone numbers takes into consideration of the following:

1. Region Format
2. Carrier

Basically, for example if I have a France number such as:

01 41 68 22 30

I'm unable to dial it on a North American iPhone device running under US/Canada Region Format.

When I switch the region format to France, I'm still unable to dial from my iPhone (not simulator). I'm wondering if this is something carrier specific?

I'm able to dial north american numbers. But still need the canOpenUrl validation to pass before I can even attempt to dial the tel:// url. That's the issue here.

Does anyone have any insight/comments?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Brian, I am facing the similar problem. Were you able to find the cause and solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:), it doesn't look like it:

> This method guarantees that that if
>   `openURL:` is called, another
>   application will be launched to handle
>   it. It does not guarantee that the
>   full URL is valid.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of `canOpenURL:` is that it simply checks to see whether the URL scheme (the part before the ://) is supported by any application on the device. To place a call, you use the tel:// scheme, which is supported by iPhone but not by iPod touches.

`canOpenURL:` does not do any additional validation, such as to check whether the URL being sent to the target application is valid input.

Comment: I'm able to dial north american numbers. But still need the canOpenUrl validation to pass before I can even attempt to dial the tel:// url. That's the issue here.

Comment: Why do you need it to pass? What are you expecting to happen?